# HTMLEncode in Winforms

Tags: c#, html-encode

I have a Winform application in which I am checking if a fully qualified file name `c:\somefolder\my file name.txt` exists in the XML.

Unfortunately, the XML holds the strings html encoded so `c:\somefolder\my file name.txt` becomes `c:/somefolder/my%20file%20name.txt` (not the change from backslash to forwardslash, and the %20 instead of blankspace).

How do I HTMLEncode strings in my winform app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(foo);
```

you will need to add a reference to System.Web.dll

Comment: `HttpUtility` uses `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` internally, which is part of `System.Net` namespace. You don't need the System.Web reference, at least in .NET 4.5. See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/R/3bd101fc1e269617.html

Answer (score 2):

You may also Try **Uri.EscapeDataString(STRING_HERE)** (No reference required), works in Asp.net & WinForms.

Comment: I believe that escapes a URL, not HTML.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The above sample text is not HTML encoded but URL encoded.